# Error activating Conda environment in Windows

Tags: windows, tensorflow, conda

I was attempting to use anaconda to download tensorflow. I followed the guide character by character. Anaconda downloaded and installed. I used the command:

`c:>conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5`

which worked, then I used:

```
c:> activate tensorflow
```

Which failed to change to a # prompt.  So I tried using `pip install` and got an error message:

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Make sure the path to your Anaconda binaries is in your PATH system variable.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: Clarification: once you are inside your `tensorflow` environment) `conda install tensorflow` would be the command for actually downloading/installing TensorFlow.   `conda create tensorflow` simply creates an environment that you decided to call `tensorflow`, and `activate tensorflow` or `source activate tensorflow` (depending on which OS/terminal window you are in) is used to start that environment.   My understanding of your question is that you cannot activate your conda environment, (called `tensorflow`) hence downloading/installing TensorFlow isn't working ?

Comment: Here as SO answer to editing your PATH variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows.  Otherwise, I'd suggest a Google search, as there are several methods.

Comment: Sometimes with anaconda you have to update python once and it will instal pip, setuptools etc. properly then. Not sure why this is sometimes the case but i've found that. I also do NOT recommend using `conda install tensorflow` as @SherylHohman suggests. You should use pip to install tensorflow.

Comment: @JCooke That was what I origionally attempted, but was unable to do.

Comment: It could be that pip isn't installed or updated as it sometimes happens. Try `conda update python` and see what happens/ It might suggest installing pip alongside some other tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to use:
`conda create -n tensorflow tensorflow python=3.5`

the conda command:
`conda install -n <env_name> <package>`

translates your code
`conda install -n tensorflow pythong-3.5`
tells conda to:
- create a new environment,
- that you want your new environment to be named `tensorflow`, and to
- install python version 3.5 in the environment you just created.

You did not actually tell conda to install TensorFlow.

Personally, I prefer to name my environment, then change into it to install packages:

```
conda create -n new_env_name python=3.5 
source activate new_env_name
conda install tensorflow numpy pandas matplotlib
```

***** Note: if you are on Windows, you *may* need to use `activate my_env_name` instead of `source activate my_env_name` to start your environment.
Which command to use is dependent on what terminal window you are using:
- Powershell requires `activate my_env_name`,
- Git Bash requires `source activate my_env_name`.
Often instructions naively state the the former is *always* used when on a Windows system.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but it doesn't seem to be able to find the meta data.

Answer (score 0):

Try `source activate tensorflow`.

On mac and in *some* windows environments `source activate <env_name>` is required.  `activate <env_name>` is used instead in *some* Windows' environments.

For example, on Windows, if you're in a Git Bash terminal window, you must use `source activate <env_name>`, but if you're in a Powershell terminal window, then `activate <env_name>` would be required.

Linux/Mac will always (so far as I know) require `source activate <env_name>`

Comment: I'm using conda on windows

Comment: then try `source activate tensorflow`.  I use Git Bash as my terminal window on Wndows 7 Pro,  and `source activate <env_name>` is what I must use.  Many instructions nievly state that `activate <env_name>` is used on Windows.  This is *sometimes* true (ie if using Powershell), but not always (ie if using Git Bash).

Comment: (C:\Users\Kyle\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Kyle>source activate tensorflow
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: What happened when you tried `activate tensorflow` ?

Comment: just got the download I'll find out once I can interact again.

Answer (score 0):

**Run Anaconda Prompt as an administrator**

I just have the same problem and by this way it's fixed.